# Asphalt Game: airborne is not showing up in the menu or games in Lumia

Tags: apps

I have installed asphalt  from SD card instead of directly downloading using my phone. But after my asphalt 8 got update it is not showing in menu or start screen nor in an Xbox game. When I am opening store for downloading it again, it is showing "installed". Last night it got updated, but not showing up in my phone menu.
Please help me out to remove the game.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the app in the store, and viewing its page. At the bottom of the screen, where you'd find the `[Install]` button (on apps you don't have), there should instead be a `[View]` button that will take you to the place in the app list where the app is located.

Alternatively (assuming you're on WP8.1), you can delete the app using `Storage Sense` (from `Settings` or the app list). Tap on `phone` or `SD card` - whichever the app is installed *to* (not installed *from*) - and then on `apps+games`. It may take a while to load, but you should be able to look through the list for the game. Tap on it, then on `[uninstall]`. If you don't see it in the first list you look through, try the other one (maybe you put it on the SD card by accident?).

Comment: When I checked in store it shows as `view` and, As you mentioned, I have checked in Phone and SD from storage sense.. Still, I can't see my app.